# Pivot duplicate column names and get all values for columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

**EXPLAINATION**

Imagine that I have 2 tables. `FormFields` where are stored column names as values, which should be pivoted and second table `FilledValues` with user's filled values with `FormFieldId` provided.

**PROBLEM**

As you see (below in *SAMPLE section*) in `FormFields` table I have duplicate names, but different ID's. I need to make that after joining tables, all values from `FilledValues` table will be assiged to column names, not to Id's.

What I need better you will see in *OUTPUT* section below.

**SAMPLE DATA**

`FormFields`

```
ID   Name  GroupId
1    col1     1
2    col2     1
3    col3     1
4    col1     2
5    col2     2
6    col3     2
```

`FilledValues`

```
ID  Name  FormFieldId  GroupID
1     a       2           1
2     b       3           1
3     c       1           1
4     d       4           2
5     e       6           2
6     f       5           2
```

**OUTPUT FOR NOW**

```
col1    col2    col3
 c       a        b  -- As you see It returning only values for FormFieldId 1 2 3
                     -- d, e, f are lost that because It have duplicate col names, but different id's
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
col1    col2    col3
 c       a        b
 e       f        d
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT  FF.Name  AS NamePiv, 
            FV.Name  AS Val1     
    FROM FormFields FF
    JOIN FilledValues FV ON FF.Id = FV.FormFieldId      
) x
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Val1)
    FOR NamePiv IN ([col1],[col2],[col3])
) piv
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/164e0/1)**

How can I produce the OUTPUT with the multiple rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using PIVOT the data is being aggregated so you only return one value for each column being grouped.  You don't have any columns in your subquery that are unique and being used in the grouping aspect of PIVOT to return multiple rows. In order to do this you need some value. If you have a column with a unique value for each "group" then you would use that or you can use a windowing function like `row_number()`.

`row_number()` will create a sequenced number for each `FF.Name` meaning if you have 2 `col1` you will generate a `1` for a row and a `2` for another row.  Once this is included in your subquery, you now have a unique value that is used when aggregating your data and you will return multiple rows:

```
SELECT [col1],[col2],[col3]
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    FF.Name  AS NamePiv, 
    FV.Name  AS Val1,   
    rn = row_number() over(partition by ff.Name order by fv.Id)
  FROM FormFields FF
  JOIN FilledValues FV ON FF.Id = FV.FormFieldId        
) x
PIVOT
(
  MIN(Val1)
  FOR NamePiv IN ([col1],[col2],[col3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/164e0/3). The output is:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|------|------|------|
|    c |    a |    b |
|    e |    f |    d |
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, there is a little problem in some `Groups` are all FormField values empty (no values at all), how can I avoid selecting these rows? Here is SQL Fiddle, added GroupId 3 with all empty values. This line shouldn't be selected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2961a/1

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Use a where clause to filter out the blank `FilledValues` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2961a/3

Answer (score 2):

Just adding `GroupId` in `Pivot source` query will fix your problem

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  FF.Name  AS NamePiv, 
        FV.Name  AS Val1,
        ff.groupid
FROM FormFields FF
JOIN FilledValues FV ON FF.Id = FV.FormFieldId      
) x
PIVOT
(
MIN(Val1)
FOR NamePiv IN ([col1],[col2],[col3])
) piv
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/164e0/6)

Comment: Thank you for an answer, there is a little problem in some `Groups` are all FormField values empty (no values at all), how can I avoid selecting these rows? Here is SQL Fiddle, added GroupId 3 with all empty values. This line shouldn't be selected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2961a/1

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - Simple filter should fix that problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2961a/2 or based on the requirement extend the filter

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when formfieldid % 3 = 1 then name end) as col1,
       max(case when formfieldid % 3 = 2 then name end) as col2,
       max(case when formfieldid % 3 = 0 then name end) as col3
from FilledValues
group by GroupID;
```

It is unclear what the rule is for assigning a value to a column.  This uses the remainder, which works for your input data.